# Call a function after closing a jqgrid edit form?

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I want to call a function after closing an edit form in jqgrid.

How is this accomplished?  Many Thanks.

This is the beginning of the edit form code.

```
jQuery("#PClist")
    .jqGrid('navGrid','#pagerPC',{edit:true, add:true, del:true, search:false, refresh:false}, 
       //Edit Section                
       {modal:true, closeAfterEdit:true, reloadAfterSubmit: true, closeOnEscape:true, editCaption: "Edit Record.", bSubmit:"Save and Close", width:450, recreateForm: true,
                beforeShowForm: function(form) {
```

Updated information:  Apparently "beforeShowForm" must be last.  I had tacked the "inClose" on the end and was getting a syntax error on the comma I inserted after the "beforeShowForm" method.

This code works:

```
jQuery("#PClist")
    .jqGrid('navGrid','#pagerPC',{edit:true, add:true, del:true, search:false, refresh:false}, 
       //Edit Section                
       {modal:true, closeAfterEdit:true, reloadAfterSubmit: true, closeOnEscape:true, editCaption: "Edit Record.", bSubmit:"Save and Close", width:450, recreateForm: true,
        onClose: function() { alert("In onClose"); }, beforeShowForm: function(form) {
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `onClose` callback parameter of form editing (like `beforeShowForm` callback which you already use). Try

```
onClose: function() {
    alert("In onClose");
}
```

The results could be a little different depend on the version of jqGrid and the fork which you use. I tried the code in current version (4.10.0) of [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) and it works as expected.

**UPDATED**:

```
jQuery("#PClist").jqGrid('navGrid', '#pagerPC',
    {edit:true, add:true, del:true, search:false, refresh:false}, 
    //Edit Section                
    {
        modal:true,
        closeAfterEdit:true,
        reloadAfterSubmit: true,
        closeOnEscape:true,
        editCaption: "Edit Record.",
        bSubmit:"Save and Close",
        width:450,
        recreateForm: true,
        beforeShowForm: function(form) {
            /*some code*/
        },
        onClose: function() {
            alert("In onClose");
        }
    }
);
```

Comment: Thank you for the response.  I am having trouble implementing this.  Please see my "answer" below.  I put the code there so it would format better.

Comment: @RayMarsh: I don't see any answer. It's better if you click on "edit" link below of **the question** and modify (append) it with additional information: your new code which not work. You should always write which version of jqGrid you use.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion Oleg.  I did figure out what was wrong but am unsure as to why.  Please see my edits on the original question.

Comment: @RayMarsh: It seems exactly what I wrote you and the code works. The code fragment `beforeShowForm: function(form),` contains syntax error because if you start the definition of the anonymous function then you have to include at least empty body of the function like `beforeShowForm: function(form) {},`

Comment: Oh great, I will.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This is the code I tried.

```
jQuery("#PClist")
    .jqGrid('navGrid','#pagerPC',{edit:true, add:true, del:true, search:false, refresh:false}, 
       //Edit Section                
       {modal:true, closeAfterEdit:true, reloadAfterSubmit: true, closeOnEscape:true, editCaption: "Edit Record.", bSubmit:"Save and Close", width:450, recreateForm: true,
                beforeShowForm: function(form), onClose: function() { alert("In onClose"); } {
```

It resulted in: "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ,"

Comment: I got it, apparently beforeShowForm likes to be last.  I switched it around and it worked.  

Many Thanks.

Comment: The code have syntax error. What is `beforeShowForm: function(form)`??? It sould be probably `beforeShowForm: function(form) {/*some code*/}`. Where is the end on the statement? Your original code and this one is finished with opening `{`.

Comment: See **UPDATED** part of my answer.

Comment: I'm not sure about that Oleg.  This is code that I inherited and am modifying so I do not know why it is like that.  The funny thing is the person that wrote it doesn't know either.  He got the code example from somewhere and used it.  I still have a great deal to learn about jqgrid.

Thank you for all your help.

Comment: I just figured it out.  There is code after the beforeShowForm.  There is a great deal of code there.  I did not realize that it was part of that bracket.  It makes a lot of sense now that I know what it is doing.